# emacs - set shortcut key only in major mode?

Tags: emacs

I would like to override `C-l` and use it to do `M-x erase-buffer` followed by simulating hitting `RET`, only when I am in `m-shell-mode`. `C-l` should be its default, `recenter-top-bottom`, otherwise. How do I do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `m-shell-mode` is based on `comint-mode`, which is true of many modes that provide a shell to interact with another process, then you can pass the `return` keypress to matlab with the function `comint-send-input`. In that case the following code should do what you want:

```lisp
(defun clear-and-return () 
  "Erases the buffer, and then passes a return to the buffer process.
Assumes the buffer is attached to a comint process."
  (interactive)
  (erase-buffer) 
  (comint-send-input))

(defun my-m-shell-mode-hook ()
  (local-set-key (kbd "C-l") 'clear-and-return))

(add-hook 'm-shell-mode-hook 'my-m-shell-mode-hook)
```

The first defun makes a function that does what you want. The second is a hook function that will bind `C-l` to that function for the buffer that is active when the function is called. The `add-hook` tells emacs to run the second function whenever you start `m-shell-mode`. You can add further m-shell-mode customizations inside the body of `my-m-shell-mode`, and Emacs will run all of them each time you start the mode.

If `m-shell-mode` is not based on `comint-mode`, you need to find out what happens when you press `return`. From a buffer that is running the mode, type `C-h k RET` to find the function bound to the return key. Use that function instead of `comint-send-input` in the code above.

Answer (score 5):

Not sure what `m-shell-mode` is, but if it's a well-defined [major mode](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Major-Modes.html), then the following should do the trick:

```
(require 'm-shell-mode)
(define-key m-shell-mode-map (kbd "C-l") 'erase-buffer)
```

Might I suggest an alternative binding, which has the same visual effect, but keeps the buffer contents around (which can be handy).

```
(defun shell-clear-command (&optional a)
  "\"clear\" the screen"
  (interactive "P")
  (recenter (or a 0)))
(define-key m-shell-mode-map (kbd "C-l") 'shell-clear-command)
```

Comment: definitely meant `m-shell-mode`, it is a MATLAB terminal. Any way I could also simulate hitting the ENTER key? Basically `erase-buffer` will clear the MATLAB command window; hitting ENTER will bring up the `>>` prompt (I know it's there, but it's a visual thing I guess).

Comment: @Dang Koa, alternative binding you might want to try out.

Comment: @TreyJackson, what is shell-clear-command? I don't see that in my Emacs (24..94.1) or google.

Comment: @Tyler sorry, I forgot that was something I brewed up, I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can add to your `m-shell-mode` hook the following code:

```
(local-set-key (kbd "C-l") 'erase-buffer)
```